# Who was the audience of the letter to the Corinthians?

Tags: 1-corinthians, local-church

> 1 Paul, called as an apostle of Jesus Christ by the will of God, and
> our brother Sosthenes, 2 To the church of God which is in Corinth, to
> those who have been sanctified in Christ Jesus, saints by calling,
> with all who in every place call on the name of our Lord Jesus Christ,
> their Lord and ours: 3 Grace to you and peace from God our Father and
> the Lord Jesus Christ. (1 Corinthians 1:1-3)

Was "the **church** of God which is in Corinth" an individual congregation or a multitude of congregations? How can we know?

Meaning of the word **Church** in this passage:

1. Hypothesis #1: A group of small individual congregations.
2. Hypothesis #2: A large individual congregation.

Comment: It could have been either but we do not know.